# a question on closed immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f:X \to Y $ is a closed immersion,by definition,$X$ is isomorphic to a closed subscheme of $Y$,so is there any connection between X and $f(X)$ ? When X is isomorphic to $f(X)$ as schemes?

Comment: May I ask how you are defining the structure sheaf on $f(X)$?

Comment: @KennyWong as a closed set of Y,at least we have the reduced induced structure

Comment: @KennyWong sorry for so lately reply, about this question,Algebraic geometry by Robin Hartshorne gives an explicit explanation (on page86),and you can refer to it.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply too. Perhaps we can show that $X$ is isomorphic to this $f(X)$ iff $X$ is a reduced scheme? I haven't thought about this too carefully, but see Georges Elencwajg's anwer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374944/questions-on-reduced-induced-closed-subscheme