# Does every point of a scheme define a closed subscheme of that scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Given a scheme $X$, we know that there is a bijection between the points in $X$ and closed, irreducible subsets of $X$. Does that mean that every such point defines a closed subscheme of $X$ as it is the case for affine schemes? (Even if we don't hit all closed subschemes)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your question.  Are you essentially just asking whether every closed subset of $X$ can be turned into a closed subscheme?  (You say you know that each point of $X$ corresponds to a closed irreducible set, so the only remaining thing would be to turn that closed irreducible set into a closed subscheme...)

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, what I meant is basically if I can turn any irreducible closed subset into a subscheme (in a unique way)? I was thinking about a point  $p$ in an affine scheme defining a closed subscheme $V(p)$ having the closure of $p$ as underlying space and if that construction also works for general schemes?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374944/questions-on-reduced-induced-closed-subscheme

Comment: I think the notion you're looking for is the **induced reduced structure** on a closed subset of a scheme.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's right :)